# Understanding the role of closure in decorators and function wrapper arguments

Tags: python, function, closures, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand in the following code, how it is that arguments passed to the decorated function seem to be passed to the argument in the wrapper function:

```
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(*args, **kwargs))
   return func_wrapper

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)

print my_get_text("John")

# <p>Outputs lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

From trying to Google, I've gathered that the inner function `func_wrapper()` has access to variables or objects in the enclosing scope through closure (I think I'm understanding this correctly anyway).

What I'm not understanding is how, exactly, the value of the argument `name` passed to `get_text(name)` is accessed by (or given to or assigned to) `*args` or `**kwargs` in the inner function `func_wrapper()`.

I think I'm correct in understanding that the entire `get_text(name)` function and its argument `name` is passed to `p_decorate()` and so is available in the scope within `p_decorate()` — but how are the arguments passed to `func_wrapper()` allowed to access the argument passed to `get_text(name)`? What is the process or methods involved that allow that to happen?

Comment: You know that you are not using decorator syntax, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye Class methods are not the only functions that can be decorated.

Comment: @Lav that is true but irrelevant. The point is the lack of `@`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What does lack of `@` has to do with anything? It's just some Python syntax sugar and has no direct relevance to the question. Please read Python documentation carefully.

Comment: @Lav not to be an asshole, or anything, but please check my profile (and thefourtheye's, for that matter). We know what we're talking about. Then read that first comment again carefully; all they're saying is that the OP isn't using the decorator syntax, i.e. `@`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe And he might have pretty good reason for this. `@`-syntax is the first thing everyone sees when they start learning about decorators, from the question it's pretty obvious OP already went quite further than that.

Comment: @Lav yes, so? Let the OP comment and say that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)`, you set `my_get_text` to the result of calling `p_decorate(get_text)`.  The result of calling `p_decorate` is your `func_wrapper`.  So when you call `my_get_text`, you are effectively calling `func_wrapper`.

Then look at what `func_wrapper` does.  It accepts any arguments (`*args` and `*kwargs`) and passes them to `func`.  Since `func` was set to `get_text` when you called `p_decorate`, this calls `get_text` with the same arguments that `my_get_text` was called with.

You are right that there is a closure, but the closure doesn't really have anything to do with how the arguments in the call `my_get_text("John")` are passed.  The role of the closure is to ensure that the value of `func` (namely, `get_text`) is "saved" in `func_wrapper`, so that the returned wrapper "knows" which function it is wrapping.  But once the wrapped function is created, the actual argument-passing that occurs when you call it is just normal argument-passing.  You call one function with arguments, and that function calls another function with the same arguments.  It is no different than this:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x+y

def bar(x, y):
    return foo(x, y)
```

If you now call `bar`, it calls `foo`.  `foo` is called with the same arguments because `bar` calls it with the same arguments `bar` was called with.  Likewise, in your example `get_text` gets the arguments because `func_wrapper` calls `get_text` with the same arguments `func_wrapper` was called with.

Answer (score 1):

When you call...

```
my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
```

...function `p_decorate()` is executed with `func = get_text`. It defines a new function `func_wrapper()` which thus has access to `func` as it was set at the time of function definition.

So, the return value of `p_decorate()` is a newly minted function with signature of `func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` which also conveniently has access to `func` variable. Note that calling `p_decorate()` again will create a **different** `func_wrapper()` function with a different `func` variable.

Now, when you call this newly created function:

```
my_get_text("John")
```

You're essentially calling the equivalent of:

```
def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    func = get_text
    # ...
```

Sunce you're calling it with a single positional argument, it is equivalent to `args = ("John",), kwargs = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. Variable defined in function defenition is defined in this functions local scope, which is an enclosing scope for any inner functions and therefore this variable is available in these inner functions. And function name (`func` in your code) is just variable referencing function object.
2. `*args` syntax in function defenition says "collect all unmatched positional arguments as a tuple and give this tuple the name `args`", `**kwargs` says "collect all unmatched keyword arguments as a dictionary and give this dictionary the name `kwargs`". `args` and `kwargs` are just a convention (so as `self` in classes) and you can use any name in this place, though you shouldn't. In function call the same syntax `*` and `**` does the opposite - it breaks a tuple and dictionary respectively in individual values and key=value pairs.

Now your code:

```
def get_text(name):
   #name is here in local scope and it's just a positional argument
   #if you've used get_text(*args, **kwargs) you could refer to 'name' as 'args[0]'
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
   #'func' is saved here in local scope
   #here 'func' will reference 'get_text' from your example
   def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       #'args' and 'kwargs' are here in local scope and
       #they represent all arguments passed to decorated function
       #regarding your example here will be 'arg[0]="John"'
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(*args, **kwargs))
       #in the line above in function you basicly break 'args' and 'kwargs'
       #into pieces and pass them to func as separate arguments
       #regarding your example you basicly call 'func("John")
       #where "John" is in 'arg[0]' and considering 'func' reference
       #in your example it's basicly 'get_text(name)'
   return func_wrapper
   #line above returns function object which will be assigned
   #to some name as result of decorator call, i.e. 'my_get_text'

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
#effectively it says "set 'my_get_text' to reference 'func_wrapper'
#with argument 'func'='get_text'"

print my_get_text("John")
#effectively is says "call function referenced by 'my_get_text'
#which is 'func_wrapper' with argument 'John'  is equal
#to call 'func_wrapper("John")'"

# <p>Outputs lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

Using `*args` and `**kwargs` makes decorator more universal. In your example, if you know that only one argument is used you could write something like:

```
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(single_argument):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(single_argument))
   return func_wrapper

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)

print my_get_text("John")

# <p>Outputs lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

Hope this will make it clearer to understand.

And regardin decorator syntax mentioned in comments to your question, usin `@` is just syntactic sugar so:

```
def p_devorate(func):
    ...

@p_decorate
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)
```

is the same as:

```
def p_devorate(func):
    ...

def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

get_text = p_decorate(get_text) 
#redefining the name of original function to pointed to wrappe function instead
```